# Genrerate n numbers based on a string

Tags: encryption, hash, keys

I wanna generate a list of numbers based on a unique string. They shouldn't be predicatble and every time to generate they are the same.

Could someone help me pleeease :)?

Comment: Use SHAKE-128 or HKDF to get a deterministically pseudo-random stream of bits, then use rejection sampling to turn a series of bits into a number in the necessary range. See the question linked above.

Comment: Hiiiii  :-)   I think that your question need some work.  Specifically last sentence. Is what predictable, repeatable, unique??? More than two sentences would help us to help you.